pnp get another site
I am in one sharepoint site and want to get the news from another one
I have my method
async function fetch(sp: SPFI, filterSite: string = null) {
  try {
    const myurl = "https://mygroup.sharepoint.com/sites/my-other-site";
    const web1 = Web(myurl);
    const web2 = Web([sp.web, myurl]);
    const web3 = Web(myurl).using(SPFx(this.context));

    const web3Info = await web3();
    const web2Info = await web2();
    const web1Info = await web1();

any of these await methods throws

Error: No observers registered for this request.
(https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/queryable/queryable#no-observers-registered-for-this-request)
at Proxy.execute (queryable.js:85:1)
at Proxy.start (timeline.js:185:1)

where is the problem?

what does work
import { spfi, SPFI } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/fields";
import "@pnp/sp/search";
import { AssignFrom } from "@pnp/core";


const DEFAULT_SITE_URL = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/my-news-site";
export const SITE_PAGES_RELATIVE_PATH = "/SitePages";

async function fetch(sp: SPFI, filterSite: string = null) {
  try {
    const CATEGORY_FILTER = "Category eq 'Promoted'";

    const siteUrl = filterSite || DEFAULT_SITE_URL;
    const spNews = spfi(siteUrl).using(AssignFrom(sp.web));

    // Extract the relative path for the list URL
    const url = new URL(siteUrl);
    const relativePath = url.pathname + SITE_PAGES_RELATIVE_PATH;

    // Fetch the items from the "Site Pages" list
    const propoNews = await spNews.web.getList(relativePath).items
      .filter(CATEGORY_FILTER)
      .orderBy("Created", false)
      ();


Below should work.
const web2 = Web([sp.web, myurl]);

Ensure the webs are imported
Import ‘@pnp/sp/webs’


it should, probably, but does not, I import { IWeb, Web } from "@pnp/sp/webs";

What action you are trying to do in Web? Do you want to read the web properties or access the lists and so? I am accessing list directly like below and its working.
const oWeb = Web([this.sp.web, siteURL]);
const submissionItem = await oWeb.lists.getByTitle("ListName").items.select("Title", "Detail")();
Try accessing the list data after the web is initialized

solved in the posted answer
